Has any NFL quarterback besides Aaron Rodgers ever completed 3 or more Hail Mary passes?
At the end of the first half of the 2024 NFL Week 6 game between the Buffalo Bills and the New York Jets, Jets QB Aaron Rodgers completed the 4th Hail Mary pass of his career.
Early in the second half, ESPN showed a chyron about Rodgers' pass that said:

fourth hail mary (most since 2008)

That would suggest that before 2008, there was another NFL QB who completed 4 or more Hail Mary passes.
I also found an ESPN article that said the following:

It was the fourth Hail Mary touchdown of Rodgers' career; no other player had more than two since 2008.

That would suggest that before 2008, there was another NFL QB who completed 3 or more Hail Mary passes. It would also suggest that after 2008, there was another NFL QB who completed 2 Hail Mary passes.
I looked at the Wikipedia List of Hail Mary passes article, and did not see any NFL QB besides Rodgers with more than 2 Hail Mary completions (Steve Bartkowski and Tim Couch were the only ones in the list with two). But it is possible that the list is not comprehensive. Also, it is possible that ESPN uses a different definition for "Hail Mary" than Wikipedia does. The NFL uses a different definition for "Hail Mary" than Wikipedia does. (As an example, this Top 10 Hail Mary Plays of All Time video from the official NFL YouTube account includes the Brett Favre Hail Mary against the 49ers in Week 3 of the 2009 season. Wikipedia says that play does not qualify as a Hail Mary.)
So has any NFL QB besides Aaron Rodgers ever completed 3 or more Hail Mary passes?
Also, has any NFL QB besides Rodgers, Bartkowski, and Couch completed 2 Hail Mary passes?

"That would suggest that before 2008, there was another NFL QB who completed 4 or more Hail Mary passes." Or I suspect more likely, ESPN only started tracking this stat in 2008.

That may be the case, which means there should be a QB besides Rodgers who has completed 2 Hail Mary passes after 2008.


Also, has any NFL QB besides Rodgers, Bartkowski, and Couch completed 2 Hail Mary passes?

According to an ESPN article from Oct. 30, 2019, Andy Dalton has also completed 2 Hail Mary passes:

There have been 193 Hail Mary attempts since the start of the 2009 season, according to ESPN Stats & Information tracking, including the regular season and playoffs. They have produced 16 touchdowns, including three from the arm of Green Bay Packers quarterback Aaron Rodgers. (The Cincinnati Bengals' Andy Dalton is the only other quarterback with more than one during that span, having twice hit receiver A.J. Green on such plays.)

Here are videos of those 2 plays:

2013, Week 10, Bengals vs Ravens (end of regulation)
2016, Week 7, Bengals vs Browns (end of first half)

In addition, Andy Dalton completed a 25-yard pass to Tyler Eifert at the end of regulation in Week 16 of the 2019 season against the Dolphins. The NFL considers that play to be a Hail Mary, so that means Andy Dalton has completed 3 Hail Mary passes.
